# Django Testing: How to test similar code

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, testing, tdd

Let's say i have 4 django model-fields i have customized in this manner:

```
# This adds an extra argument 'rs_serial' to the fields that subclass this
#
class RsBaseFieldMixin(models.Field):
    def __init__(self, *args, rs_serial=None, rs_arg2=None,.... ,**kwargs):
    self.rs_serial = rs_serial
    self.rs_arg1 = rs_arg1
    self.rs_arg2 = rs_arg2
    ...
    ...
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

class RsCharField(models.CharField, RsBaseFieldMixin, metaclass=models.SubfieldBase):
    pass

class RsDecimalField(models.DecimalField, RsBaseFieldMixin, metaclass=models.SubfieldBase):
    pass

class RsIntegerField(models.IntegerField, RsBaseFieldMixin, metaclass=models.SubfieldBase):
    pass

class RsBooleanField(models.BooleanField, RsBaseFieldMixin, metaclass=models.SubfieldBase):
    pass
```

**Q1**: Do i test the 4 custom fields, or just the mixin? My guess is the 4 fields, since i want to test functionality (as in end-result: i want a decimalfield with an rs_serial-argument etc), not the implementation.

I can create seperate tests for every customized field type, and every argument (this is a simplified model, in reality i have a lot of extra arguments and a lot more field-types). But i could create a for loop:

```
class TestFields(TestCase):

    for ft in ['RsDecimalField','RsCharField','RsBooleanField', andsoon]:

        for arg in ['rs_serial', 'rs_arg2', 'rs_arg3' ... andsoon]:
            ...
            ... [ assertEqual(ft.arg, myexpectedvalue) ]
            ...
```

**Q2** Is this a wrong way to test? If so, why, and how *should* i test them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, you need to test two things -

1. First, that mixin is working as expected.
2. Secondly, that all three classes are inheriting from that mixin.

So, if your mixin provides three operations, you can test all three operations in mixins. In classical TDD sense, you would ensure that at least one of that operation is working in all inherited classes.